# C++ keeping access to protected member (of the function argument) when specializing base template class

Tags: c++

could anyone please help to resolve this (the problem is persistent under both GCC and VC++).

```
template <class T> class A{  
protected:  
    T a;  
public:  
    A(int aa=0){a=aa;}  
    virtual ~A(){}  
    virtual void plus(A const *AA){a=a+AA.a;}  
};  

class B:public A<int>{  
public:     
    B(int bb=0):A<int>(bb){}  
    virtual ~B(){}  
    void plus(A<int> const *AA){a=a+AA->a;} //<--PROBLEM: I can access a but not AA->A?  
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected.

An instance of B has no right poking around in the internals of an **arbitrary** A; it has a right only to access the A part of (other) Bs. That's what the **protected** keyword means.

Comment: thanks -- while i was waiting for the answer I stripped down the code off templates and the problem became more apparent. so, the "only" (reasonable) resolution is declare B as friend?

Comment: @Yuriy: Basically this is indicating a design problem. But yes, you can work around making B a friend.

Comment: @Yuriy: No need to use friend. See my response.

Comment: could you suggest a better design (if it does not require too much effort/typing, of course). what I want to do is: declare class A<typename T>, derive from it specialized B that would re-implement some of A's behavior but more efficiently?

Comment: Thanks again -- I just realized what I need to do:)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with compilers but standard conformant behaviour. You can access protected members of a base class only through `this` (implicitly or explicitely).

Answer (score 0):

This should look like:

```
class B:public A<int>{  
public:     
    B(int bb=0):A<int>(bb){}  
    virtual ~B(){}  
    void plus(A<int> const *AA){this->A::plus(AA);}
};
```

No need to reimplement the plus function in the derived class if it's doing the same.

Comment: Thanks! B::plus is to be customized, so is not doing the same (only in the example above it does)

Answer (score 0):

"UncleBens" has already answered your main question, but some details...

First:

```
virtual void plus(A const *AA){a=a+AA.a;}
```

Since `AA` is a pointer you can't do `AA.a`... ;-)

Second, be aware that member pointers do not generally honor accessibility. Using just implicit conversions you can gain access to a base class' protected stuff. Member pointers are to accessibility about the same as what `goto` is to flow control.

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf